# Simple onClick return function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function:

```
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        function calcEstimate(instrument, damage)
        {
            var cost = 0;
            if (instrument.value == "guitar" || instrument.value == "bass")
            {
                cost = Number(damage.value) * 150;
                document.getElementById('txtCost').value = cost;
            }
            else
            {
                cost = Number(damage.value) * 300;
                document.getElementById('txtCost').value = cost;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And a form with some inputs:

```
            <form style = "border: solid white 1px; width:35%;" name = "calculator">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th style = "font-size: 20px;" colspan = 3;> Select your instrument: </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> Percussion: </th>
                    <th> Strings: </th>
                    <th> Brass: </th>
                </tr>   

                <tr> 
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "keyboard_piano">Keyboard/ Piano. </td>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "guitar">Guitar. </td>                       
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "bass">Trumpet. </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "bass_drum">Bass drum. </td>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "bass">Bass. </td>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "trombone">Trombone. </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "snare_drum">Snare drum. </td>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "violin">Violin. </td>                       
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "tuba">Tuba. </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "tom_toms">Tom-toms. </td>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "cello">Cello. </td>                     
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "ride_cymbal">Ride Cymbal. </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "crash_cymbal">Crash Cymbal. </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "hi_hat">Hi-hat. </td>
                </tr>                       

            </table>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th style = "font-size: 20px;"> Scale of damage: </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "damage" value = "1">1. Slight damage, cracks. </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "damage" value = "2">2. Some broken parts. </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "damage" value = "3">3. Parts missing, broken off, may be unplayable. </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "radio" name = "damage" value = "4">4. In pieces, completely unplayable. </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <input type = "button" name = "calculate" value = "Calculate" onClick ="calcEstimate(instrument,damage);">
                        <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "Reset Form">
                    </td>
                </tr>                   

                <tr>
                    <th style = "font-size: 20px;"> Estimate: </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type = "text" id="txtCost" name = "cost" size = 25> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

I want to be able to select the radio button `instrument` and the radio button `damage`, click the `calculate` button and pass `damage` and `instrument` to **function calcEstimate**, where it will do the calculations and return the variable `cost`. However, when I click the calculate button, nothing happens at all. I've made many other attempt and have searched the internet, but nothing I find seems to be helping.

Comment: Your first mistake was using `onclick` inside of your html. That has never been a good practice.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with onclick inhtml

Comment: I was able to run your code in firefox and chrome and the js ran and populated the cost box with 150. Your logic doesn't necessarily look correct, but functionally this is working.

Comment: @MistressDavid Everything is wrong with `onclick` in html.

Comment: What? I use it all the time. Why?

Comment: @MistressDavid It's not hard to find your answer. https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS535US535&oq=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.3562j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: MistressDavid: It works, but it's bad for maintainability. You should strive for a separation of concerns: HTML describes the structure of the document, js describes interactive elements, just like css describes presentation. By keeping these things modular and separate it gives you the most flexibility to make changes and understand the structure of the various things involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript would be:

```
var damageValue = 0;
function getDamage(val){
  damageValue = val;
}
function calcEstimate(instrument, damage)
            {
                var cost = 0;
                if (instrument.value == "guitar" || instrument.value == "bass")
                {
                    cost = Number(damageValue) * 150;
                    document.getElementById('txtCost').value = cost;
                }
                else
                {
                    cost = Number(damageValue) * 300;
                    document.getElementById('txtCost').value = cost;
                }
            }
```

and your html would be like this:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "instrument" value = "guitar">Guitar.
<input type = "radio" name = "damage" value = "1" onclick="getDamage(this.value);">

<input type = "button" name = "calculate" value = "Calculate" onClick ="calcEstimate(instrument,damage);">
<input type = "text" id="txtCost" name = "cost" size = 25>
```

Please make sure you have a instrument and calculate object as you use it above. If not you should try to learn javascript more than now.

Comment: This populated the box with "NaN", which is better than absolutely nothing. I edited my original post with the full code, since i only pasted the part i thought was causing problems. Also, I am making this webpage for school, and the function must have a return in it, which is making it a little more difficult for me.

Comment: So did you check instrument.value and damage.value? if not please check it with alert() function.

Comment: I just checked them, and it says "undefined" for both of them?

Comment: Yes Sir! That's why your cost is NaN, because It's result of undefined multiply 300.

Comment: I have just updated my answer! Put onclick="getDamage(this.value);" in each your radio button. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that worked. And i actually get how it works, so that is very helpful as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
<label><input type="radio" name="instrument" value="guitar">Guitar</label>
<label><input type = "radio" name="damage" value="1">Damage</label>

<button name="calculate">Calculate</button>
<input type="text" name="cost" size="25">
```

[js: live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/ONOKire/2/edit)

```
/* Get your element references */
var instrument = document.querySelector('input[name=instrument]');
var damage = document.querySelector('input[name=damage]');
var calculate = document.querySelector('button[name=calculate]');
var cost = document.querySelector('input[name=cost]');

calculate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  cost.value = calcEstimate(instrument.value, damage.value);
});

function calcEstimate(instrument, damage) {
  var cost = 0;
  if (instrument.value == "guitar" || instrument.value == "bass") {
    cost = Number(damage) * 150;
  }
  else {
    cost = Number(damage) * 300;
  }
  return cost;
}
```